# Java Stream difference between map and mapToObj

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I don't feel the difference between `map()` and `mapToObj()` methods in Java 8 Streams. In both we can create and return objects to the streams, so why these methods exist as two, not only one.

Could you give me the explanation with examples?

Comment: They only exist on the primitive streams, where `map` works for mapping the primitive type to itself, e.g. `IntStream.map(IntOperator)`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You will see this cool pattern. The `Stream` classes includes a `IntStream`, `LongStream`, `DoubleStream` etc. This is so that you can use primitive types in stream operations. Because otherwise you have to use `Stream<Integer>` or `Stream<Double>`, which will box the values.

Similarly, the `map` methods also do this. In the `Stream<T>` class, there are `mapToInt`, `mapToDouble` methods, but the situation is a little bit different in the `IntStream`, `DoubleStream` classes.

In `IntStream`, the `map` method takes an `IntUnaryOperator`, which maps an int to an int. If you want to map the stream to a `Stream<T>`, you have to use `mapToObj`. `mapToObj` is a good name because it distinguishes from the `map` that maps to ints. It signifies that the stream changes from a `IntStream` to a `Stream<T>`. The reason why `mapToObj` is named like so is the same reason why `mapToInt` is named like so - to signify a change in the `Stream` type/

Comment: You might add a mention of the `boxed()` method which transfers between eg `IntStream` and `Stream<Integer>` and fits into this pattern.

Answer (score 47):

The primitive and object versions of data types (i.e. `int` and `Integer`, `double` and `Double`, etc.) are not really compatible with each other in Java. They are made compatible through the extra step of **auto-boxing/unboxing**. Thus, if you have a stream of primitive ints and if you try to use the object versions of `Stream` and `Function` (i.e. `Stream<Integer>` and `Function<Integer, Integer>`), you will incur the cost of boxing and unboxing the elements.

To eliminate this problem, the function package contains primitive specialized versions of streams as well as functional interfaces. For example, instead of using `Stream<Integer>`, you should use `IntStream`. You can now process each element of the stream using `IntFunction`. This will avoid auto-boxing/unboxing altogether.

Thus, whenever you want to process streams of primitive elements, you should use the primitive specialized streams (i.e. `IntStream`, `LongStream`, and `DoubleStream`) and primitive specialized functional interfaces (i.e. `IntFunction`, `IntConsumer`, `IntSupplier`, etc.) to achieve better performance.

One more thing to note is that none of the primitive specialized functional interfaces (such as `IntFunction`, `DoubleFunction`, or `IntConsumer`) extend the non-primitive functional interfaces (i.e. `Function`, `Consumer`, and so on).

`java.util.function package` contains `int`, `double`, and `long` (but no `float`) versions of all the functional interfaces. For example, there is an `IntFunction`, a DoubleFunction, and a `LongFunction`, which are `int`, `double`, and `long`, versions of Function. These functions are used along with primitive specialized versions of streams such as `IntStream`, `DoubleStream`, and `LongStream`.

Let's take some examples:

```
Stream<Object> stream1 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3); //Will compile fine
IntStream intStream1 = IntStream.of(4, 5, 6); //Will compile fine

Stream<Object> stream2 = IntStream.of(4, 5, 6); //Does not compile
Stream<Object> stream3 = IntStream.of(4, 5, 6).mapToObj(e -> e); //mapToObj method is needed
IntStream intStream2 = Stream.of(4, 5, 6).mapToInt(e -> e); //mapToInt method is needed
```

As a conclusion, the reason you might use `mapToObj` is the same as you might use `mapToInt`, which is to change the `Stream` type.